# For loop save value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How can I save value in `for` loop? Here my problem :

```
var n = $('ul#myID li').lenght;
var placetop = $('.position-for-li').offset().top;
var place = $('.position-for-li').offset().left;
for ( var y=0;y<n ;y++) {
 var pos = $('.list-update li:eq(' + y + ')').offset().left;
var postop = $('.list-update li:eq(' + y + ')').offset().top;
 var sumleft = place - pos;
 var sumtop = placetop - postop;
 alert(sumleft);
}
$('#myID li').click(function() {
     var X = $(this).prevAll().length;
     if ( X == 0) {
       $(this).animate({
          'left': test, <----- HERE VALUE FROM MY LOOP SUMLEFT
          'top' : test2 <----- HERE VALUE FROM MY LOOP SUMTOP
       });
     } else if ( X == 1) {
           $(this).animate({
          'left': test, <----- HERE VALUE FROM MY LOOP SUMLEFT
          'top' : test2  <----- HERE VALUE FROM MY LOOP SUMTOP
    } 

});
```

So in first part in want to count how much px i should add to left and top. Then i use click function to my li image and it moves to correct position.

Comment: no you are not wrote it clearly..

Comment: you given return inside for loop.. make it outside

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` for your `for`

Comment: `return` to where? Show all relevant code and explain what this code should do. You have a loop generating a value each iteration but no indication of what that value will be used for

Comment: FYI: `.size()` has been deprecated since 1.8. Use `.length`

Comment: .lenght return undefined i don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement inside the loop is a bug. Take it outside...

```
function myListStuff(){
    var placetop = $('.position-for-li').offset().top;
    var place = $('.position-for-li').offset().left;
    $('ul#myID li').forEach(function(li, index){
        var pos = $('.list-update li:eq(' + index + ')').offset().left;
        var postop = $('.list-update li:eq(' + index + ')').offset().top;
        var sumleft = place - pos;
        var sumtop = placetop - postop;
    })
    return sumleft
}
```

Comment: Sorry my friend  i wrote my first 'harder function' i don't know that i can't use that much value sorry.

Answer (score 0):

put your `return sumleft` statement outside the for loop and do the declarations outside for loop as below

```
var n = $('ul#myID li').size();  // it's return how long is my LI = 3 
var placetop = $('.position-for-li').offset().top; // Give me a position of my li 
var place = $('.position-for-li').offset().left; // give me a position of my special space for new position li 
var sumleft=0, sumtop=0;
for ( var y=0;y<n ;y++) {
 var pos = $('.list-update li:eq(' + y + ')').offset().left; 
 var postop = $('.list-update li:eq(' + y + ')').offset().top;
 sumleft += place - pos; // it say me how much i should add to my li to move it 
 sumtop += placetop - postop; //

}
return sumleft;
```

Comment: how would this help? Will only return value of last iteration

Comment: @charlietfl I updated my answer. I think this is what you meant

Answer (score 0):

Your `for loop` looks like its purpose is to calculate positions for new elements, but you don't seem to be setting them anywhere. Instead of returning a value, could you just **use** the outcome of your calculations?

```
for (var y=0;y<n ;y++) {
   var pos = $('.list-update li:eq(' + y + ')').offset().left; 
   var postop = $('.list-update li:eq(' + y + ')').offset().top;
   var sumleft = place - pos; // it say me how much i should add to my li to move it 
   var sumtop = placetop - postop; //

   // set the top and left css properties of elements: 
   // .myElementToPosition0, .myElementToPosition1, .myElementToPosition2
   $('.myElementToPosition' + y).css({
       'left': sumleft + 'px', 
       'top': sumtop + 'px'
   });
}
```

If this doesn't help, maybe you could add a short description explaining what you wanted to happen with the values from your calculation loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I don't know why .size(); is working but .lenght no but thank you man :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok man lets take a view..

if you set a var in your for, over it the value will be deleted, so declare the value first

```
var n = $('ul#myID li').size();  // it's return how long is my LI = 3 
var placetop = $('.position-for-li').offset().top; // Give me a position of my li 
var place = $('.position-for-li').offset().left; // give me a position of my special space for new position li 

var sumleft,
    sumtop;

for ( var y=0;y<n ;y++) {
 var pos = $('.list-update li:eq(' + y + ')').offset().left; 
 var postop = $('.list-update li:eq(' + y + ')').offset().top;

sumleft = place - pos;
sumtop = placetop - postop; 
}
//use sumleft and sumtop with new values
```

remember that vars are only in your for if they're allocated locally.
same as if()else:

```
EXAMPLE
var x=0
for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
   x++;
var y=0;
   y++;
}
alert(x); -> x+1 for five times (5)
alert(y); -> undefined
var y=0;
alert(y); -> 0
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. :)